# Terrafom Azure SQL Server add user role

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure, terraform

I am creating a terraform infrastructure with a Linux service app in .NET an AZure SQL Server database
I want to use user assigned identity to access my database from my API.
For this I try to add rights to my user but I take a timeout. I launch terraform from Azure devops.

I would be in a private area so no direct access to the BDD

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "sql_server_managed_identity" {
  name                = "sql-server-${local.domain}-managed-identity"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.app_resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.app_resource_group.name
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql_server" {
  name                         = "sql-${local.domain}-business"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.app_resource_group.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.app_resource_group.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  minimum_tls_version          = "1.2"

  azuread_administrator {
    azuread_authentication_only = false
    login_username              = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.name
    object_id                   = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.principal_id
  }

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.id]
   }

   primary_user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.id
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "sql_database_test" {
  depends_on     = [azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server]
  name           = "sqldb-${local.domain}-test"
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.id
  collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI"
  read_scale     = false
  ledger_enabled = false
  sku_name       = "S3"
  zone_redundant = false
  tags           = local.app_tags
}

resource "mssql_user" "web" {
  server {
    host = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.fully_qualified_domain_name
    azuread_managed_identity_auth {
      user_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.id
    }
  }
  database  = azurerm_mssql_database.sql_database_test.name
  username  = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.name
  object_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.client_id
  roles     = ["db_datareader", "db_datawriter"]

  timeouts {
    default = "2m"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand why I have a timeout in the user assignment task and roles in the BDD

Comment: To grant access to the SQL Server database, use a user-assigned managed identity in the configuration. The managed identity may not be available for use immediately after creation. By setting a timeout, Terraform can delay assigning roles to the user until the identity is active, which ensures a successful configuration. @dna

Comment: So what is the solution there

Comment: mention if you face any blocker with this configuration @dna if your question is something what you mention in above comments you got that answer for that in my replay. If you're facing any blocker please share

Comment: I don’t understand what I miss and what it’s wrong to have the timeout error

Comment: Help me please. I am blocked

Answer (score 0):

> Terrafom Azure SQL Server add user role

The cause of the timeout error is that the network is blocking the terraform instance from connecting to the `SQL Server` database. You should check your firewall settings and make sure that your `public IP` is allowed to access the database.

Here is the updated terraform code to create SQL database and assign **db_datareader** and **db_datawriter** to the user assigned managed identity.

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        mssql = {
          source = "betr-io/mssql"
          version = "0.3.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "mssql" {
      debug = "false"
    }
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "sql-server1"
      location = "eastus"
    }
    resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "sql_server_managed_identity" {
      name                = "sql-server-managed-identity1"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
      name                         = "abddjdddhdbfhr1"
      resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      version                      = "12.0"
      minimum_tls_version          = "1.2"
      administrator_login          = "Venkatadmin"
      administrator_login_password = "Welcome@123$"
    
     azuread_administrator {
        login_username = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.name
        object_id      = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.principal_id
      }
     identity {
        type         = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.id]
      }
      primary_user_assigned_identity_id            = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.id
      depends_on = [ azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule" "sql_server_fw_rule" {
      name             = "AllowIP-myip"
      server_id        = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
      start_ip_address = "<add your public IP>"
      end_ip_address   = "<add your public IP>"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "sql_database" {
      depends_on     = [azurerm_mssql_server.example]
      name           = "sqldb-test1"
      server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
      collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI"
      read_scale     = false
      ledger_enabled = false
      sku_name       = "S3"
      zone_redundant = false
    }
    resource "time_sleep" "wait_50_seconds" {
      depends_on = [azurerm_mssql_database.sql_database]
    
      create_duration = "50s"
    }
    
    resource "mssql_login" "server" {
      server {
        host = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.fully_qualified_domain_name
        login {
          username = azurerm_mssql_server.example.administrator_login
          password = azurerm_mssql_server.example.administrator_login_password
        }
      }
      login_name = azurerm_mssql_server.example.administrator_login
      password   = azurerm_mssql_server.example.administrator_login_password
    
      depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_50_seconds]
    }
    
    
    resource "mssql_user" "web" {
      server {
        host = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.fully_qualified_domain_name
     login{
       username = azurerm_mssql_server.example.administrator_login
       password = azurerm_mssql_server.example.administrator_login_password
     }
      }
      database  = azurerm_mssql_database.sql_database.name
      username  = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.name
      object_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.sql_server_managed_identity.client_id
      login_name = mssql_login.server.login_name
      roles     = ["db_datareader", "db_datawriter"]
      depends_on = [ mssql_login.server ]
    }
```

After running the script, the role has been assigned to user assigned managed identity.

**Terraform apply:**

[image]